# Quelle serait une façon plus courante de dire la phrase citée dans les détails?

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

> L’agent de filature l’a **frimée**: il l’a séduite, il lui a fait boire plusieurs verres (verre sur verre) dans un court laps de temps et l’a fait arrêter par des collègues patrouilleurs peu de temps après qu’elle a pris le volant au sortir du bar. La dame fait maintenant face à des accusations de conduite en état d’ébriété.

C’est le verbe « frimer » qui me semble pas correct (un verbe que je ne connaissais pas jusqu’à tout récemment d’ailleurs et dont aucune définition ne semble correspondre au sens attendu selon le contexte dans lequel il est employé).

Si je me reporte au contexte concerné (et à la phrase en question), j’imagine que « frimer » a le sens de « faire de quelqu’un la victime d’une illusion, d’une feinte, d’une comédie, d’une machination, d’un coup monté, d’une manigance ». Je cherche avant tout un verbe qui serait synonyme dudit verbe sans avoir à recourir à une expression (phrase composée de plusieurs mots). Le verbe qui, à mon sens, cadrerait le mieux avec la phrase serait « tromper », mais il est fort possible que je me trompe…

Comment: D'où vient ce texte ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je ne connais pas ce sens de "frimer".

Tromper est possible car le reste de la phrase évite toute ambiguïté.

Voici d'autres propositions (qui postulent que le sens est bien celui que tu donnes à frimer), en gras celle que je choisirais :

> L'agent de filature l'a manipulée.
> L'agent de filature l'a dupée.
> L'agent de filature l'a **piégée**.

Answer (score 0):

Au Québec, "Frimer" veut aussi dire "Attribuer une valeur spéciale à (une carte à jouer)." [image: Antidote, Frimer]

Answer (score -1):

Je ne pense pas que *frimer* puisse avoir le sens que tu lui donnes dans ton explication. L'agent de filature a bien trompé la femme pour la faire arrêter, ceci est implicite par la suite du récit mais pas contenu dans *frimer*. Le seul emploi transitif de *frimer* que je connaisse, et répertorié dans les dictionnaires, est celui, argotique, de :

> **Dévisager, regarder avec insistance** (pour identifier, par curiosité, insolence).
> *P'tit Louis*. – Dis-donc, eh ! t'as frimé lesquels c'étaient les poulets ?
> *Dédé*.  – Y a l'grand blond, tu sais, çui qu'avait emballé Julot.
> *P'tit Louis*. – Saintini ?
> *Dédé.* – Oui.
> (E. Bourdet,  *Fric-Frac*)
>
> [...]
> *Être frimé* **identifié, reconnu** (par des regards indiscrets).
> vous ne pouvez pas manger comme un porc dans n'importe quel restaurant : le taulier est peut-être un indic, et vous, vous êtes tricard du coin et vous ne voulez pas être frimé.
> (A. Sarrazin, *La cavale*)

Extrait du *Dictionnaire du français non conventionnel* (Jacques Cellard et Alain Rey).
Ce sens est aussi mentionné dans le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/frimer) (2**B**).

Dans la mesure où le reste du texte est de style soutenu, *dévisagée* ou *regardée avec insistance* conviendrait peut-être mieux.  Il l'a dévisagée dans le but de la séduire.
Le contexte étant insuffisant sur le déroulement des faits on peut aussi comprendre que l'agent de filature l'ayant identifiée il l'a ensuite abordée pour la séduire, etc. À ce moment tu peux remplacer par « reconnue ».